# geth - web3 : checkBalance not supported

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Here is what I did :

Terminal 1 :

```
geth --syncmode "light"
```

Terminal 2 :

```
geth attach
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")
Error: not supported
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at get (web3.js:6091:38)
    at <unknown>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not using light sync mode and not using web3js, but it works for me.  Perhaps update geth to the latest version (my version is: `Geth/v1.8.27-stable/linux-amd64/go1.10.5`)

```
# geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545/
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")
4710
```

and I'm on a private network >:)